# Why does the set of real numbers with irrationality measure $\gt 2$ have zero measure?

Tags: diophantine-approximation

Recall the irrationality measure of a real number $r$ is $$
\mu(r)= \inf \left\{ \lambda\colon \left\lvert r-\frac{x}{y}\right\rvert\lt \frac{1}{y^{\lambda}} \text{ has only finitely many solutions} \right\}$$

Does anyone have a reference or proof?

Comment: Would you mind terribly accepting answers to some of the other questions you have asked?

Comment: Concerning accepting answers - please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers

Comment: I think it will not be $0$, more like (in the interval $[0,1]$ measure $1$.

Comment: Andre, yes youre right. Sorry, I meant the set of real numbers that have irrationality measure larger than 2.

Answer (score 5):

A proof of the fact that the set of reals with irrationality measure $\gt 2$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ can be found in several places. I think the result is due to Khinchin, and is in his book on continued fractions.

Here is [an online proof](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~beuke106/Pi-artikel.ps) by Beukers. It is towards the end of the paper, but independent of the rest, which anyway is worth reading.

It follows that the set of reals in the interval $[0,1]$ with irrationality measure $2$ has Lebesgue measure $1$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be established using the Borel-Cantelli Lemma. First note that is suffices to assume that $r \in (0,1)$ as otherwise we could just consider rational approximations shifted by an integer. Now define sets $E_n$ as follows:
$$ E_n = (0,1) \cap\bigcup_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}-\frac{1}{n^{2+\epsilon}}, \frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2+\epsilon}} \right), \; n \geq 1 $$
for some $\epsilon>0$. Then the statement that there exist infinitely many solutions to
$$ |r-\frac{x}{y}|<\frac{1}{y^{2+\epsilon}} $$
is equivalent to the statement that $r \in E_n$ for infinitely many of the $E_n$. But $m(E_n) = \frac{2}{n^{1+\epsilon}}, \; n \geq 1$ and so for all $\epsilon>0$ the sum $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m(E_n) $ converges. The Borel-Cantelli Lemma now applies and we conclude the set
$$ E = \{ r \in (0,1) | r \in E_n \text{ for infinitely many } n\} $$
has measure zero.